# How to get enumerator for more than one sub-items of an object in C#?

Tags: c#, enumeration

Here is my class

```
class EmissionSource:IEnumerable
{
    private Emissions[] emissions = new Emissions[5];
    private Contribution[] contributions = new Contribution[2];

    public EmissionSource()
    {
        emissions[0] = new Emissions(2010, 400, 200, 6);
        emissions[1] = new Emissions(2011, 450, 255, 16);
        emissions[2] = new Emissions(2012, 470, 245, 26);
        emissions[3] = new Emissions(2013, 490, 285, 36);
        emissions[4] = new Emissions(2014, 495, 245, 46);


        contributions[0] = new Contribution(1, "Energy");
        contributions[1] = new Contribution(3, "Industrial Sector");
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return emissions.GetEnumerator();
    }

}
```

In the GetEnumerator method, I am delegating the request to the System.Array using emissions object. I was wondering, how can I iterate through other subitem viz contributions like

```
    foreach (Emissions e in source)
    {
        //
    }
    foreach (Contribution e in source)
    {
       //
    }
```

Comment: Why did you make emissions and contributions object private, when you do want to make them expose outside? if you want to make both enumerable implement them in different class or make them public and use like property. Note array are by default enumerable.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya If you make them public you can change them from anywhere. That's information hiding.

Comment: Did you try [`yield return`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) inside your foreach loops?

Comment: @Verarind No that won't work. What determines here which array to iterate over is the OP's point here.

Comment: @Rouf Why would you want to do that? Are you sure you don't want a hierarchy? e.g. contributions by year

Comment: @JenishRabadiya Sorry, I didn't see any expected result. For me it's not clear what he's trying to do exactly.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya

The activities at an emission source say "A Cement Industry" emit greenhouse gas emissions. An emission source contributes to emissions for various IPCC defined sectors. Here "A cement Industry" contributes to the emissions in Energy Sector and Industrial Sector. Similarly, a power plant may contribute to Energy Sector and Waste Sector. 
So, there is an has-a relationship of Emission Source to Contributions and Emissions. 

Now, If we are able to iterate through the one object in has-a relationship, shouldn't we be able to do it for the other one?

Comment: @Servé Laurijssen I will go with your first approach, but still wondering if can we achieve it using generic versions of IEnumerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can come up with is just using two different properties:

```
class Main
{
    class X
    {
        private int[] i = new int[5];
        private string[] s = new string[2];

        public X()
        {
            i[0] = 0; i[1] = 1; i[2] = 2; i[3] = 3; i[4] = 4;
            s[0] = "test"; s[1] = "test2";
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> Strings
        {
            get
            {
                return s;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<int> Ints
        {
            get
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        X x = new X();

        foreach (string s in x.Strings)
        { }

        foreach (int i in x.Ints)
        { }
    }
}
```

I've tried using the generic versions of IEnumerable and inherit from both int and string but I couldnt get that to work probably because the generic versions inherit from the non-generic IEnumerable again making it a diamond shaped inheritance tree. Maybe you can use it as food for thought.

```
class X : IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<string>
{
            private int[] i = new int[5];
            private string[] s = new string[2];

            public X()
            {
                i[0] = 0; i[1] = 1; i[2] = 2; i[3] = 3; i[4] = 4;
                s[0] = "test"; s[1] = "test2";
            }

            public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
            {
                return i.GetEnumerator();
            }

            IEnumerator<int> IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return (IEnumerator<int>)i.GetEnumerator();
            }

            IEnumerator<string> IEnumerable<string>.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return (IEnumerator<string>)i.GetEnumerator();
            }
}
```